# Openvidu-react-native changes are not visible when using emulator

Tags: react-native, openvidu

changes applied to OpenVidu-react-native package appears on the android phone but on not on the emulator even after clearing everything in App.js the one built with the emulator works just fine.Is this something to be worried about for production purposes??

The changes to be applied not showing